# I am new to data structures and feeling quite confused about time complexity of recursive function

Tags: recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying to find its time complexity and found it to be O(n). Since each time loop is called we get time complexity of for loop getting decreased by one. So summing up number of times for loop runs each time print() is called, I got O(n). Am I right? Can you suggest me resources for learning more on time complexity of recursive functions?

pseudo code

```
print(n){
if(n==0)
   return 0;
else 
{ 
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
       printf("%d", i);
    }
 return print(n-1);   
}

main(){
n=6;
print(n);
}
```

Comment: The number of iterations of the `for`-loop in `print(n)` is `n`. But then, in addition to this loop, you make a recursive call to `print(n-1)`; which also has a `for`-loop with `n-1` iterations, plus a recursive call to `print(n-2)`; ... In the end, you get `n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1` which is a well-known series that sums up to `n(n+1)/2`. Hence the total complexity is approximately proportional to `n²`, not just `n`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I missed it .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are confused about time complexity of recursive functions or about how big O notation works.

To make sure we are on the same page consider the following example:

```sh
for (int i = n; i > 0; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    print(j)
  }
}
```

The outer loop iterates `n` times and the inner loop iterates `i-1` times for each iteration of the outer loop. The sequence of how many times the inner loop iterates is of the form: `n, n-1,... 2, 1`. This is equal to `n * (n+1)/2`.

What is happening in your code is quite similar to this nested loop.

At each stage of the function call, you check the base case `n == 0`, when it isn't true, code continues to print `0...n` and recursively call itself with `n-1`. At some point, `n == 0` and the base case hits and your function returns preemptively, before calling itself again.
This whole process is nothing else but the nested loops that I showed above. It's of the same time complexity. While the iterations aren't strictly `n^2` in big O notation we only care about the highest degree member of each quantity. That's why time complexity is quadratic.